# Does android support the PTRACE_SINGLESTEP?

Tags: android, linux, ptrace

OK, this is a simple question.Does android support the  PTRACE_SINGLESTEP when I use ptrace systemcall?  when I want to ptrace a android apk program, I find that I can't process the SINGLESTEP trace. But the situation changed when I use the PTRACE_SYSCALL, It can work perfectly. Does the android wipe out this function or arm lack some supports in hardware? Any help will be appreciated！thanks.

this is my core program:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {   
    if(argc != 2) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,TAG,"please input the pid!");
      return -1;
    }
    if(0 != ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, target_pid, NULL, NULL))
   {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,TAG,"ptrace attach error");
    return -1;
   }
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,TAG,"start  monitor process     :%d",target_pid);
    while(1)
    {
    wait(&status);
    if(WIFEXITED(status))
    {
        break;
    }
if (ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, target_pid, 0, 0) != 0)
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,TAG,"PTRACE_SINGLESTEP attach error");
    }
ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, target_pid, NULL, NULL);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,TAG,"monitor finished");   
return 0; 
    }
```

I run this program on shell. And I can get the root privilege. 
  If I change the request to PTRACE_SYSCALL the program will run normally.
  But if the request is PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, the program will get an error!

Answer (score 4):

PTRACE_SINGLESTEP has been removed on ARM Linux since 2011, by [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=425fc47adb5bb69f76285be77a09a3341a30799e).

The HW has no support for single-stepping; previous kernel support involved decoding the instruction to figure out which one's next (branches) and temporarily replacing it with a debug-break software breakpoint.

Quoting a mailing list message about the same commit, describing the old situation: http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2011-February/041324.html

> PTRACE_SINGLESTEP is a ptrace request designed to offer single-stepping
> support to userspace when the underlying architecture has hardware
> support for this operation.
>
> On ARM, we set `arch_has_single_step()` to 1 and attempt to emulate
> hardware single-stepping by disassembling the current instruction to
> determine the next pc and placing a software breakpoint on that
> location.
>
> Unfortunately this has the following problems:
>
> 1. Only a subset of ARMv7 instructions are supported
> 2. Thumb-2 is unsupported
> 3. The code is not SMP safe
>
> We could try to fix this code, but it turns out that because of the
> above issues it is rarely used in practice.  GDB, for example, uses
> PTRACE_POKETEXT and PTRACE_PEEKTEXT to manage breakpoints itself and
> does not require any kernel assistance.
>
> This patch removes the single-step emulation code from ptrace meaning
> that the PTRACE_SINGLESTEP request will return -EIO on ARM. Portable
> code must check the return value from a ptrace call and handle the
> failure gracefully.
>
> Signed-off-by: Will Deacon <will.deacon at arm.com>
> ---
>
> The comments I received about v1 suggest that:
>
> - **If emulation is required, it is plausible to do it from userspace**
> - ltrace uses the SINGLESTEP call (conditionally at compile-time since    other architectures, such as mips, do not support this
>   request) but    does not check the return value from ptrace. This is a
>   bug in ltrace.
> - strace does not use SINGLESTEP

Comment: NVM, found it & fixed.

Comment: What is the status quo in 2019?

Comment: @Cyker: AFAIK, still gone.  Presumably no clean way to do it in the kernel that's fully SMP-safe (you're supposed to be able to ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP) one thread without disrupting other threads), and it's a lot of code to have in the kernel just for this.  Unless AArch64 introduced new HW support, still gone.  A recent duplicate [Troubles at singlestepping on ARM machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65434215) confirms that it's still not present on 32-bit Raspberry Pi in late 2020, using IDK what software version.